# How can a software code be made modifiable without being visible to the end user?

Tags: c++, software, closed-source, product

I wish to supply a software product with GUI, etc. for operating it. And the software utility is research so the users will want to tweak it to some extent and implement their own preferred algorithms instead of the ones we're shipping. Therefore, we want to make the code partly modifiable but not visible.

A possible solution here would be to provide a library with certain functions that are overridable and a documentation is provided to define their input/output.

Is this the best solution to the problem or are there better well known alternatives to the same.

The reason I want to achieve this is because the original code would lose value if exposed totally.

So basically I want to not reveal my code in the best possible way. I don't want to obfuscate it as it may not be a good practice for a research based software.

Comment: What problems are you thinking you will have? Just release the software, while offering a plugin API, or just ability to switch out dynamically loaded libraries (in this case you should really provide sources for a reference implementation of the libraries, perhaps releasing them under LGPL).

Comment: I want the software to be as closed-source as possible because I think the barrier in making this software will drop significantly once I make entire code public.

Comment: OpenCV is BSD licence, Qt offers dual licensing so just speak to whoever owns Trolltech nowadays and purchase a commercial licence.

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you're asking. Are you asking whether it's possible to release closed source software with LGPL dependencies? How to satisfy the LGPL without revealing source? How to expose an API without revealing your implementation thereof? Are you asking us to find OpenCV's license for you? (most of those questions have been asked millions of times and the answers should be easy to search for)

Comment: I have edited the question, please indicate any further changes required for reopening of question

Comment: Look into plug in architecture. You'd also be interested in the Visitor and Listener patterns. Perhaps also the Decorator pattern. Being these are algorithms you think your users will want to plug in, maybe they could implement a Command to provide in the place of your own implementation. There are lots of ways to skin this cat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are trying to do is make an *extensible* application: one that has pluggable functionality, perhaps with sensible defaults.

Ideally, you would have a framework such as [Spring](https://spring.io/) to allow plugging in functionality: however, with C++, this is a bit more work that typing in some XML.

The general way to accomplish this in C++ is through dynamic libraries that override functionality in the base application.

For example, perhaps you have an algorithm to frobnicate widgets. You provide an interface `Frobnicator` with pure `virtual` methods that *must* be implemented. Your application supplies a `DefaultFrobnicator` which has a typical implementation. During startup, your initialization logic tells your `FrobnicatorFactory` that you want to use `DefaultFrobnicator`. Now whenever you want to frobnicate widgets, you ask the factory for the frobnicator and it returns the default instance.

**But wait!** One of your customers wants a *different* implementation of `Frobnicator`. They implement a class that inherits `Frobnicator`, supplying their custom implementation. Their DLL initialization logic tells `FrobnicatorFactory` to use their own implementation. Now *your* code that the customer has no access to will call into the customer code *and the customer does not need access to your full source:* only the portions relevant to frobnicating widgets.

The final piece is that during startup, your application will perform its own initialization, then load arbitrary dynamic libraries in predefined locations.

The details about a dynamic library entry point and how it works are platform-specific. On Windows, there is a [DllMain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), while Linux has [different mechanisms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12463718). Alternatively, you could have a static global object in your library that performs initialization logic: this is guaranteed to run when your library is loaded regardless of platform.

---

```
class Frobnicator {
  public:
    virtual void frobnicate(Widget&) const = 0;
};

class FrobnicatorFactory {
  public:
    static void setFrobnicator(Frobnicator) { .. }
    static Frobnicator& getFrobnicator() { ... }
};

// Some code...
Widget w(...);
FrobnicatorFactory::getFrobnicator().frobnicate(w);

// Application init
FrobnicatorFactory::setFrobnicator(DefaultFrobnicator());

// Library init, define once.
class DllInitializer {
  public:
    DllInitializer() {
      FrobnicatorFactory::setFrobnicator(CustomerFrobnicator());
    }
} x; // Note the creation here
```

---

Note that this is a basic overview of how *plugins* work in C++. That is essentially what you are trying to do: expose a plugin mechanism to your customers without providing full source code.

Also note that your customers will need to use the same compiler as you due to name mangling.

Comment: The software will be deployed in Ubuntu. So on searching for plug-ins and dynamic library entry points in Linux/C++, I reached this [dynamic loading](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3687) . Can you explain little more on what practice to follow, if the dynamic library that I am creating is itself running the program and not just acting as a base class for polymorphism. That is, the dynamic library somehow decides for itself, probably using #ifdef etc. whether an override for the virtual function exists or not.

Comment: Eg. OpenCV checks if [Intel's IPP](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-integrated-performance-primitives-intel-ipp-open-source-computer-vision-library-opencv-faq) are present or not and calls its functions accordingly

Comment: @arttp2 sure, I will read that article and update my answer. I probably will not be able to get to it for a day or two, however.

Answer (score -4):

You're searching for software called "obfuscator". It cannot prevent everything but it can help against decompilers. Obfuscators make rje decompiled result very hard to read or even make the decompiler throw an error. The expensice obfuscators support virtualization where the sourcecode is stored encrypted intermedia language which will be loaded in in virtual machine on runtime and executed. Because this code will be executed slower you can sometimes cirtualize single methods such as auth methods which will validate product keys.

Please keep in mind that every software can be cracked. Also you can be blackboxed: Someone will analise the bahiviour of the software and will develop software that does the same/similar

Dont forget to purchase an commercial license of OpenCV because otherwise you would violate their License

Comment: What do you mean by commercial licence of OpenCv?

Comment: Read the question, the user states that he uses openCV in an comercial product. It would be nice to have people who actually use support it financially.

Comment: I dont know why my answer gets downvoted. OP doesnt want the customers to see the sourcecode and the closest anyone will get to that is with obfuscators. It would be nice to have people who would tell me what's wrong with the answer instead of downvoting it whilst there's no better answer to the question available

Comment: I am sorry for not putting it clearly but I haven't yet commercialized the software.

Comment: I did read the question. OpenCv is released under the BSD licence. It would not violate that licence to use it in a closed source commercial product. Licensing has less to do with "being nice" than cheese has to do with Quebec.

Comment: Yes but as soon as you make it available you want the customers to not be able to the the sourcecode. Wikipedia has a list of obfuscators: en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_obfuscators_for_.NET

Comment: @TZHX oh sorry you're right. I swapped that with the EmguCV license